# Python carving a file from a large set of bytes

Tags: python, hex-editors

I am working with python 3 and can not figure out a way to get this to work. I am trying to create a tool for my hex editor that can look at a large set of bytes and search for the headers and footers of .pdf files, etc. I know the .pdf header is 25 50 44 46 2D 31 2E and the footer is 25 25 45 4F 46 in hexadecimal. So my questions is, is there a way to search through a large set of bytes find the header and footer copy all the bytes in between, use them to create a new file that I can then open with, in this case something like adobe reader, and view it as any other .pdf? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this, even more than one. What have you tried to solve that?

Comment: Did you already try to open a pdf-file in binary mode and search there for those header bytes? How does the code look like with which you try and what part of it makes what problems?

Comment: I can open it in binary mode but after it's open I'm not sure how to search the file without turning the data into a string first. I also I have no idea how to copy a section of code and create a new file with it. I've looked but haven't found a way to do it.